# how do I Center images with text under and above using html and css?

Tags: css, html, image

Hello I'm new to html & css and I have a question. I'm trying to display 4 images in the center of a box next to eacht other. I'm currently using tables but that gives a lot of code in my html & css:

css:

```
/*box*/

#content2{
  margin: 30px 0;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  clear: both;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #999;
  text-align: center;
  overflow:hidden;
} 

/*table*/
table{
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 display: inline-block;
}
td,th{
 padding: 20px;
}
```

and then way to much html:

```
<div id="content2">
    <h4>Onze producten</h4>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="../html/kleding.html"> Pika deken</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="../html/kleding.html"><img src="../images/baby1.jpg"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>€20</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="../html/kleding.html">School outfit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="../html/kleding.html"><img src="../images/boy1.jpg"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>€140</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="../html/kleding.html">Bussines girl</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><a href="../html/kleding.html"><img src="../images/girl2.jpg"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>€250</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="../html/kleding.html">Summer</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="../html/kleding.html"><img src="../images/girl1.jpg"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>€99.99</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Is there any way to do this more effciently ? 
The design has to stay liquid. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you give a print screen of how the existing way looks?

Answer (score 1):

max. simplified (ok, we could use img captions, too)

http://jsfiddle.net/EpyUb/

HTML

```
<div id="content2">
    <h4>Onze producten</h4>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="product">
            <a href="../html/kleding.html">School outfit</a>
            <a href="../html/kleding.html"><img src="../images/boy1.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="product">
            <a href="../html/kleding.html">School outfit</a>
            <a href="../html/kleding.html"><img src="../images/boy1.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="product">
            <a href="../html/kleding.html">School outfit</a>
            <a href="../html/kleding.html"><img src="../images/boy1.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="product">
            <a href="../html/kleding.html">School outfit</a>
            <a href="../html/kleding.html"><img src="../images/boy1.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.product {display: inline-block;}
.product img {display: block;}
```

Comment: @ThomasPen If it helps to design it better you can change ".product img" to ".product a" to also set the Title as "display:block". PS. please accept the answer that the question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<div id="content2">
<h4>Onze producten</h4>
<div class="section">
    <a href="../html/kleding.html"> Pika deken</a>
    <a href="../html/kleding.html"><img src="../images/baby1.jpg" /></a>      
    €20
</div>
<div class="section">

    <a href="../html/kleding.html">School outfit</a>
    <a href="../html/kleding.html"><img src="../images/boy1.jpg" /></a>
        €140
    </div>
    <div class="section">          
        <a href="../html/kleding.html">Bussines girl</a>
        <a href="../html/kleding.html"><img src="../images/girl2.jpg" /></a>
            €250
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <a href="../html/kleding.html">Summer</a>
        <a href="../html/kleding.html"><img src="../images/girl1.jpg" /></a>
          €99.99
   </div>      
</div>
```

and css:

```
 #content2{
  margin: 30px auto;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  clear: both;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #999;
  text-align: center;
  overflow:hidden;
} 

.section {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
}    

.section a {
   display: block; 
   padding-bottom: 10px; 
}
```

example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/thespacebean/xGqDE/

Comment: I can not yet upvote an answer but it helped me a lot ! Tank you

Comment: I think you can 'accept' an answer even if you can't yet upvote. Cheers :)